# How to use exists for a complete list of a product?

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

This is the query to find out if a particular car has W1, W2, WA, WH conditions. How can I modify my query so that I can get a list of all the cars as yes or no for these conditions?

NOTE: Here, I have put v.[carnumber] = 't8302' but I need a complete list.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT co.[alias]    
        FROM  [MTI_TAXI].[vehicle] v
        LEFT JOIN [MTI_SYSTEM].[Conditions] co with (nolock) on v.DispatchSystemID = co.DispatchSystemID and (v.Conditions & co.conditionvalue > 0)
        WHERE co.[alias] in ('W1', 'W2', 'WA', 'WH') and v.[DispatchSystemID] = 6 and v.[CarNumber] = 't8302')    
    THEN cast ('Yes' as varchar)   
    ELSE cast ('No' as varchar)    
    END AS [WATS]
```

OUTPUT - ( WATS - No )

But, here are all the cars but I am getting yes to WATS condition which is incorrect

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k5CT.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question - can you post sample data please? From your explanation it just sounds like you need to remove `and v.[CarNumber] = 't8302'`

Comment: please provide some data for testing and post your desired output and thus we can help you. Thank you

Comment: Is there an actual requirement for this to be done using an EXISTS operator? And what is the cardinality of the relationship from [MTI_TAXI].[vehicle] to [MTI_SYSTEM].[Conditions]? If your final output will need a row for each record in [MTI_TAXI].[vehicle], regardless of what conditions they have, then it seems you might be better served rewriting this query with a simple LEFT JOIN from [MTI_TAXI].[vehicle] to [MTI_SYSTEM].[Conditions] or using an OUTER APPLY operator (depending on the cardinality).

Comment: If I remove v.[carnumber] = 't8302', then I only get yes. I do not get a complete vehicle list.

Comment: So you want every record from `[MTI_TAXI].[vehicle]`? then select from it! start with `SELECT * FROM [MTI_TAXI].[vehicle]` and go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply utilizing your provided filters and moving the `EXISTS` to be used in an `OUTER APPLY` statement:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN [find_wats].[Found] = 1 
            THEN 'Yes' 
        ELSE 'No' 
    END AS [WATS]
FROM 
    [MTI_TAXI].[vehicle] AS v
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) 
                    1 AS [Found]
                FROM 
                    [MTI_SYSTEM].[Conditions] AS co
                WHERE 
                    v.DispatchSystemID = co.DispatchSystemID 
                    AND 
                    (v.Conditions & co.conditionvalue > 0)
                    AND 
                    co.[alias] IN ('W1', 'W2', 'WA', 'WH') 
                    AND 
                    v.[DispatchSystemID] = 6) AS [find_wats];
```

Using this set up, you can then use `[find_wats].[Found] = 1` to determine that your record within the table `[MTI_TAXI].[vehicle]` found a match in `[MTI_TAXI].[Conditions]` (using your provided criteria) while still maintaining a single record in your final result set for each record originally in the table `[MTI_TAXI].[vehicle]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `count(*)` to assert that there was exactly *1* row found by adding:

```
group by co.[alias]
having count(*) = 1
```

So the whole query becomes:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT co.[alias]
      FROM [MTI_TAXI].[vehicle] v
      LEFT JOIN [MTI_SYSTEM].[Conditions] co with (nolock)
        on v.DispatchSystemID = co.DispatchSystemID
        and (v.Conditions & co.conditionvalue > 0)
      WHERE co.[alias] in ('W1', 'W2', 'WA', 'WH')
      and v.[DispatchSystemID] = 6
      and v.[CarNumber] = 't8302'
      group by co.[alias]
      having count(*) = 1
    ) THEN cast ('Yes' as varchar)
    ELSE cast ('No' as varchar)
  end AS [WATS]
```

Comment: I cannot use this in the subquery as it will still give me the value of a single car only. I need to get a list of all the cars and whether they contain w1, w2, wa, wh conditions or not. I think something must be done outside the subquery.

Comment: @AmitJoshi have you actually tried this query? `WATS` will contain `'Yes'` if all four aliases are present, `'No'` otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I tried using this query. But I need either W1 or W2 or WA or WH to be true, not all of them.

Comment: Then use `having count(*) = 1` instead.